# spring-boot application get warning: CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN_IS_UNDEFINED

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback, spring-cloud

There is a **spring-boot** *(2.0.0.RELEASE)* application as part of the **spring-cloud** *(Finchley.M9)* cluster.
On startup, it always print following line:

> CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN_IS_UNDEFINEDCONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN_IS_UNDEFINEDCONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN_IS_UNDEFINED

---

*(following are the configuration)*

**application.yml:**

```
## spring-boot configuration,

# logging
logging:
  file: "log/hello.log"
  pattern:
    console: "[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}] %-5level [%t] [%logger - %line]: %m%n"
    file: "[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}] %-5level [%t] [%logger - %line]: %m%n"
  level:
    root: INFO

spring:
  application:
    name: eric-sc-hello

server:
  port: 9191

management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
    include: "*"

eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/

eric-sc-hello:
  ribbon:
    eureka:
      enabled: false
    listOfServers: localhost:9191,localhost:9192,localhost:9193
    ServerListRefreshInterval: 15000
```

**logback-spring.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <charset>UTF-8</charset>
      <Pattern>${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN}</Pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
  <appender name="FILE"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
    </encoder>
    <file>${LOG_FILE}</file>
    <rollingPolicy
      class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
      <fileNamePattern>${LOG_FILE}.%i</fileNamePattern>
      <minIndex>1</minIndex>
      <maxIndex>10</maxIndex>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <triggeringPolicy
      class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
      <MaxFileSize>10MB</MaxFileSize>
    </triggeringPolicy>
  </appender>

  <root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

---

The warning says `CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN` is undefined for 3 times.

But `logging.pattern.console` is defined in `application.yml`, and the log lines in console is printed in the specified format.

So, why the warning pop-up, and how can I remove it?

---

### @Update

I already found some solutions, and had added an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62846599/

Answer (score 1):

I cannot explain why it's happening, but if you set `logging.config` property to smth else e.g. `my-project-logback.xml` and don't use `logback-spring.xml` name - everything is working without CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN_IS_UNDEFINED message. Documentation allows to do this.

From [Spring Boot Logging documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html):

> Because the standard logback.xml configuration file is loaded too early, you cannot use extensions in it. You need to either use logback-spring.xml or define a logging.config property.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is not directly related to your question but I was seeing similar problems using the default `org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml` appender in `Spring Boot 2.x`.

So instead of defining the `logging.pattern.console` in your application config you could directly include the `CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN` definition in the `logback-spring.xml` configuration.

`e.g.` the default config would be included like this.

```
<configuration>
 <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml">
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define Spring properties explicitly in logback-spring.xml like so:

```
    <configuration>
        <springProperty name="CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN" source="logging.pattern.file"/>

      .... rest of configuration ....
```